# Adding a txt box when certain dropdown is selected

Tags: javascript, html, drop-down-menu, textbox

I am having a problem in the script. When i select Canada from drop down list it is supposed to add a text box but it is not adding anything.

```
<style>
          #color {display:none;}
       </style>


       <script>
          (function(d){
             var options={
                val:'Canada',
                sel_id:'country',
                hid_id:'color'
             };
             var browser={
                modern:function(){
                   var method=null;
                   if(d.addEventListener) {
                      method=['DOMContentLoaded',true];
                   } else if(d.attachEvent) {
                      method=['readystatechange',false];
                   }
                   return(method);
                },
                addEvent:function(elem,event,func){
                   if(this.modern()[1]) {
                      elem.addEventListener(event,func,false);
                   } else {
                      elem.attachEvent('on'+event,func);
                   }
                }
             };
             var load=browser.modern()[0];
             var modern=browser.modern()[1];
             var init=function(){
                if((!modern && d.readyState=='complete') || modern) {
                   var select=d.getElementById(options.sel_id);
                   var input=d.getElementById(options.hid_id);
                   browser.addEvent(select,'change',function(){
                      var val=this.value;
                      var display=(val==options.val) ? 'block' : 'none';
                      input.style.display=display;
                   });
                }
             };
             browser.addEvent(d,load,init);
          })(document);
       </script>
```

This is the javascript function and below is the html code

```
<tr> 
                                            <td height="22" class="bodytxt" id="color">
                                                <font size="2" face="Geneva, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif">Date of Birth </font>
                                            </td>

                                            <td height="22" class="bodytxt" id="color">
                                                <input type="text" size="20"  name="color" value="<?=$_REQUEST['dob']?>" />


</td></tr>
```

the problem i m facing can be seen here live....

http://www.sunno.com/medical/clients/test.html

Answer (score 0):

Your html is invalid, you are not supposed to use the same id for more than one element. When you use `document.getElementById()` it will only find one of them (the first, in most browsers) - note that that method is get element (singular), not get elements (plural)...

That's why in your demo page the label appears but not the textbox (contrary to your statement in the question "but it is not adding anything").

Why don't you move the `id="color"` to the `<tr>` element that contains both items, so that you can show or hide the whole row?

Comment: Ok great i changed it and the text box is appearing now. But its on the like umm right side colliding with text. How can i move it to right with other textboxes in line?